# Converting a Windows xlsx into a Mac xlsx

Tags: microsoft-excel, mime-types, xlsx

I'm working on a process that takes data from customers and parses it into our product. In this case, an xlsx file. Unfortunately, our product is having trouble reading it because it was coded to read xlsx files created in Excel for Mac instead of Excel for Windows, and our customers are using Windows.

I'm still digging into this, but as far as I can tell the differences involve MIME types and the organization of the XML data archived into the xlsx file:

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2HWx.jpg) of two files with identical data, one saved locally on a Mac and one from a Windows machine.

Here's the results of a `file` command:

```
user@MBP:~/Desktop/win_vs_mac$ file *
mac_origin.xlsx: Microsoft Excel 2007+
win_origin.xlsx: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
user@MBP:~/Desktop/win_vs_mac$ file -I *
mac_origin.xlsx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=binary
win_origin.xlsx: application/zip; charset=binary
```

And here's what they give you when you unarchive them (these results are consistent across multiple attempts):

```
user@MBP:~/Desktop/win_vs_mac$ unzip mac_origin.xlsx
Archive:  mac_origin.xlsx
  inflating: [Content_Types].xml
  inflating: _rels/.rels
  inflating: xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
  inflating: xl/workbook.xml
  inflating: xl/sharedStrings.xml
  inflating: xl/theme/theme1.xml
  inflating: xl/styles.xml
  inflating: xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
  inflating: docProps/core.xml
  inflating: docProps/app.xml
user@MBP:~/Desktop/win_vs_mac$ unzip win_origin.xlsx
Archive:  win_origin.xlsx
warning:  win_origin.xlsx appears to use backslashes as path separators
  inflating: _rels/.rels
  inflating: [Content_Types].xml
  inflating: xl/workbook.xml
  inflating: xl/sharedStrings.xml
  inflating: xl/styles.xml
  inflating: xl/worksheets/sheet0.xml
  inflating: xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
```

After doing a ton of googling, [this thread](https://github.com/box/spout/issues/149) leads me to believe that the order that the files are added might make a difference as well.

My question is, is there a way to programmatically convert a "Win-based" Excel file into a "Mac-based" Excel file without manually opening the file and resaving it? Ideally in the Terminal? I can't find any existing tools. As a middleman sysadmin/ops type I'm not in a position to ask the customer to generate these on macOS and I'm not in a position to ask Dev to rebuild the portion of the product that reads these. I *need* to automate this or it'll drive me crazy.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Have you tried unpacking and repacking the file?

Comment: Not yet. Not sure how I would get the order right, or generate the `docProps/` files that don't exist in the Windows copy.

Comment: Don't do more work than required. Start with the easiest thing.

Comment: Try docXConverter for Mac.

Answer (score -1):

**I'm showing the easiest method and it will help you to convert Window's .Xls, .Xlsx and even .CSV file into Mac Numbers(Spreadsheet).**

1. Load the Numbers.
2. Navigate to the location of your Excel file. You can also click on the File menu and select Open, then navigate to your spreadsheet.
3. Once you’ve located the File, select it and click Open. A progress window will appear.
4. A window may appear, explaining any changes that were made during the import process.

**NB:** *The possibility is that a change had to be made. The simpler the spreadsheet, the more your file will resemble what you created in Excel.*

Now the Excel file should open in Numbers on MAC.

**Hope this help you.**

Comment: The question is about PROGRAMMATICALLY and WITHOUT MANUALLY OPENING...

Comment: Yeah @MátéJuhász,,, I know that's the reason I've mentioned in Bold on top that I'm showing you are easiest method, is of course not a VBA. It takes time to create ,, Test and then Post here,,. My Solution must be considered as "First Hand Support" ,,, the real to come ! :-)

Comment: I think my solution should not be Vote Down,,,, Converting the File Format in VBA is a HARD NUT to crack,,,,,! Wait and see how many such SOLUTIONS will appear here. :-)

Comment: besides what I've already written, you also answered a different question, (convert a "Win-based" Excel file into a "Mac-based" Excel), there is no mention of Numbers in the question. OP simply wants to convert to different xls format. "I give you answer for a different question, suggesting a method what you've already tried" deserves downvote:(

Comment: @MátéJuhász,,, For your knoweldge,,, let me remind that "NUMBER" is the name of the Spreadsheet Software what MAC uses like EXCEL for Windows OS,,! Hope now you got the point and realize your mistake!!