# Zipping while preserving relative directories from anywhere

Tags: macos, bash, zip

Trying to get a specific functionality from `zip`. I'd like to zip everything recursively in a specific directory and preserve the directory structure within from JUST that directory, but not have the fully qualified path be a part of the archive.

Let's say I have `/path/to/test/tmp/` and I want everything in `tmp/` to be zipped as if I'm running the command from within that folder.

The `-r` flag gets what I want but includes path info above the directory I need, depending on where I run it:

```
user@MBP:~/path/to/test$ zip -r myarchive.zip tmp/
  adding: tmp/foo.txt (deflated 68%)
  adding: tmp/bar/bar.txt (deflated 41%)
  adding: tmp/baz/baz/baz.txt (deflated 92%)
```

The `-j` flag cuts off everything but the filenames:

```
user@MBP:~/path/to/test$ zip -rj myarchive.zip tmp/
  adding: foo.txt (deflated 68%)
  adding: bar.txt (deflated 41%)
  adding: baz.txt (deflated 92%)
```

What I need is something that will give me this:

```
adding: foo.txt (deflated 68%)
adding: bar/bar.txt (deflated 41%)
adding: baz/baz/baz.txt (deflated 92%)
```

But that I can specify to be run from anywhere. I'm trying to script this into a cron. I can't find what I'm looking for in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip). How can I pull this off, other than actually changing directories in my script?

Comment: Looks like the Archive Manager can do that with zip files, checking it's source should lead to a solution. But are you married to .zip, it doesn't save all the linux file attributes, not interested in tar?

Comment: I used "zip" as a general placeholder. My actual use case involves .xlsx files. I describe it more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1294454/converting-a-windows-xlsx-into-a-mac-xlsx). My testing indicates that replacing "\" with "/" by unpacking and repacking resolves that original issue. Just trying to get it all into a script now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `zip` (at least the version from Info-ZIP that is on my platform) doesn't allow you to do that. (Unlike `tar`, which has the `-C`/`--directory` option, as @Xen2050 hinted.)

But, I have to ask, is it so bad to change directories in your script? Especially if you can do so in a subshell and not affect the current working directory of the script (explained in detail [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/786419/2866527)):

```
pwd
(cd /path/to/test/tmp; zip -r myarchive.zip .)
pwd    # prints the same as in line 1
```

Take note that this will store the final Zip file in `/path/to/test/tmp`.